# Откуда пошло слово "фенечка"?

Tags: этимология

Почему плетеные браслетики "на счастье" называют в народе "фенечками"? Откуда вообще взялось это слово?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фенечка получила свое название, предположительно, от англ. thing — «вещь, штука» (см. http://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Фенечка#section_1 )